# I go on the business trip

Tags: grammar, prepositions, expressions

> I go on the business trip.

Why the above sentence use "on " as the preposition but not "to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you thought of it this way, in order to go **to** *someplace*, you need to use some sort of conveyence

> going **on** a flight
>   going **on** a train

Whereas

> **to**

is often used to describe a particular location or destination

> I am going **to** London
>   I am going **on** a British Airways flight **to** London.

However, a business trip is not a particular location

> I am going **to** Sydney **on** a business trip.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Now, I got it.

Comment: Please mark the answer as "Answered" so other answerers will know.